# Binding to the selected item in an ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding, itemscontrol

I created a custom `ComboBox` as follows: (note, code is not correct but you should get the general idea.) The `ComboBox` contains 2 dependency properties which matter: `TitleText` and `DescriptionText`.

```
<Grid>
  <TextBlock x:Name="Title"/>
  <Grid x:Name="CBG">
    <ToggleButton/>
    <ContentPresenter/>
    <Popup/>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I want to use this `ComboBox` to display a wide range of options. I created a class called Setting which inherits from `DependencyObject` to create usable items, I created a `DataTemplate` to bind the contents of this `Settings` object to my `ComboBox` and created a `UserControl` which contains an `ItemsControl` which has as a template my previously mentioned `DataTemplate`. I can fill it with `Setting` objects.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myDataTemplate">
  <ComboBox TitleText="{Binding Title}" DescriptionText="{Binding DescriptionText}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<UserControl>
  <Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
      <ItemsControl Template="{StaticResource myDataTemplate}">
        <Item>
          <Setting Title="Foo" Description="Bar">
            <Option>Yes</Option><Option>No</Option>
          </Setting>
        </Item>
      </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
      <TextBlock x:Name="Description"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I would like to have the `DescriptionText` of the selected `ComboBox` (selected by either the `IsFocus` of the `ComboBox` control or the `IsOpen` property of the popup) to be placed in the `Description` `TextBlock` in my `UserControl`.

One way I managed to achieve this was replacing my `ItemsControl` by a `ListBox` but this caused several issues: it always showed a scrollbar even though I disabled it, it wouldn't catch focus when my popup was open but only when I explicitly selected the item in my `ListBox`, when I enabled the `OverridesDefaultStyle` property the contents of the `ListBox` wouldn't show up at all, I had to re-theme the `ListBox` control to match my `UserControl` layout...

What's the best and easiest way to get my `DescriptionText` to show up without using a `ListBox` or creating a custom `Selector` control (as that had the same effect as a `ListBox`)?

The goal at the end is to loop through all the items (maybe get them into an `ObservableCollection` or some sort and to save them into my settings file.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what you're trying here. Do you have a code-behind, or are you just using Binding?

Comment: I have a code behind file, but at the moment it isn't really used.
Each ComboBox contains a small description about the option it alters, when you select the ComboBox item (gets focused or the popup is open) the idea is to update the Description TextBlock on the right with the proper description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you are trying to do. Here is a possible solution.

You should use a ListBox (or anything deriving from Selector control) in order to use the SelectedItem property.

```
<UserControl>
  <Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
      <ListBox x:Name="SettingListBox" Template="{StaticResource myDataTemplate}">
        <Item>
          <Setting Title="Foo" Description="Bar">
            <Option>Yes</Option><Option>No</Option>
          </Setting>
        </Item>
      </ListBox >
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
      <TextBlock x:Name="Description"
          Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Description, ElementName=SettingListBox}"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

To solve the problem where your ListBox does not focus on the item when you open the ComboBox drop-down menu, I have an attached property that will fix that for you.

```
public class ListBoxHelper
{
    #region Dependency Property

    public static bool GetCanFocusParent(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(CanFocusParentProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCanFocusParent(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(CanFocusParentProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CanFocusParent.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CanFocusParentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CanFocusParent", typeof(bool), typeof(ListBoxHelper), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnCanFocusParentChanged));



    #endregion

    private static void OnCanFocusParentChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var element = obj as UIElement;
        if(element == null) return;

        if((bool)args.NewValue)
            element.PreviewMouseDown += FocusOnParent;
        else
            element.PreviewMouseDown -= FocusOnParent;
    }

    private static void FocusOnParent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listBoxItem = VisualUpwardSearch<ListBoxItem>(sender as DependencyObject) as ListBoxItem;
        if (listBoxItem != null) listBoxItem.IsSelected = true;
    }

    public static DependencyObject VisualUpwardSearch<T>(DependencyObject source)
    {
        while (source != null && source.GetType() != typeof(T))
            source = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(source);

        return source;
    }
}
```

What this little class does is help your control to focus on the ListBox selected item when you activate a control inside it (ie. your ComboBox). It works when the Mouse is clicked inside the ListBox item.

Now all you have to do is attach it to your ComboBox like so:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myDataTemplate">
  <ComboBox
      TitleText="{Binding Title}"
      DescriptionText="{Binding DescriptionText}"
      CotrolHelper:ListBoxHelper.CanFocusParent="true"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Where ControlHelper is:

```
xmlns:ControlHelper="clr-namespace:WhereYouPutYour.ListBoxHelperClass"
```

And finally, to Disable (but I recommend setting to Auto) the Scrollbar, you can use the ScrollViewer attached property in your ListBox like this:

```
<ListBox
    x:Name="SettingListBox"
    Template="{StaticResource myDataTemplate}"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
    <Item>
        <Setting Title="Foo" Description="Bar">
            <Option>Yes</Option><Option>No</Option>
        </Setting>
    </Item>
</ListBox >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ListBox, just change how the data is presented. For example, this code will default to not having a scroll bar. (I want scroll bars, so I have to explicitly wrap the whole thing in a ScrollViewer.)

```
                <ListBox.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" >
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ListBox.Template>
```